# How to solve $\log_3(x+7) < \log_3(5-x) +\log_3(3-x)$

Tags: inequality

Wolframalpha shows answer as `-7 < x < 1`

My solution happens to be wrong.

Comment: And your solution is… ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: Write your equation in the form
$$\frac{\ln(x+7)}{\ln(3)}<\frac{\ln(5-x)}{\ln(3)}+\frac{\ln(3-x)}{\ln(3)}$$
since $$\ln(3)>0$$ we get $$\ln(x+7)<\ln((5-x)(3-x))$$ and you have to solve
$$x+7<(5-x)(3-x)$$

Comment: Why not immediately (w/o ln):    log3(x+7) < log3((5-x)(3-x)) => (x+7) < (5-x)(3-x)

Comment: This is also possible!

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Since the log function is $\textit{monotonic}$, you can raise both sides of the inequality as powers of 3. Note that, after doing so, the right hand side should yield a quadratic equation:

$$
3^{\text{log}_3(x+7)} < 3^{\text{log}_3(5-x)+\text{log}_3(3-x)} 
$$

Now you can make use of particular "log properties" to attain a solution.